# FLRW cosmology : two open parallel universes from standard $k = -1$ metric?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor, space-expansion

My books on General Relativity do not tell anything about the following and I would like to clarify this thing.

Consider only the ***open*** FLRW universe ; $k = -1$ (also called *hyperbolic* universe), of the following metric (note :  that metric is given in Misner-Thorne-Wheeler on page 722, exe 27.4, also in Landau-Lifchitz, at the end of paragraph 111):
$$\tag{1}
ds^2 = dt^2 - \frac{a^2(t)}{(1 - r^2 /4)^2}\big(dr^2 + r^2 (d\vartheta^2 + \sin^2 {\vartheta} \; d\varphi^2) \big).
$$
Usually, we introduce a new radial coordinate :
$$\tag{2}
\tilde{r} = \frac{r}{1 - r^2/4},
$$
such that the metric (1) becomes
$$\tag{3}
ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2(t) \Big( \frac{d\tilde{r}^2}{1 + \tilde{r}^2} + \tilde{r}^2 \, (d\vartheta^2 + \sin^2 {\vartheta} \; d\varphi^2) \Big),
$$
or else
$$\tag{4}
r = 2 \tanh{(\chi/2)}
$$
(or $\tilde{r} = \sinh{\chi}$) such that
$$\tag{5}
ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2(t) \big(d\chi^2 + \sinh^2 {\chi} \, (d\vartheta^2 + \sin^2 {\vartheta} \; d\varphi^2) \big).
$$
However, these coordinate transformations bypass a particularity of metric (1) above :  it has a coordinate singularity at $r = 2$, and is still valid for $r > 2$ (remember that metric (1) describes an isotropic and homogeneous spacetime, so curvature is regular everywhere : $0 \le r < \infty$.  Curvature invariants don't even depend on $r$).  Since $\tilde{r}$ should be positive, the transformation (2) is valid only for $r < 2$.  Also, the transformation (4) is defined only if $r < 2$.

So the question is simple : **What is the part of spacetime described by $r > 2$, according to the metric (1) ?**.  **Is this another open spacetime, "parallel" to the part described by $r < 2$ ?**  Or do we have to restrict ourselves to $r < 2$ only (why rejecting $r > 2$) ?

Take note that metric (1) is invariant under the radial coordinate reversal :
$$\tag{6}
r = 4/r',
$$
so points of coordinate $r < 2$ could be mapped to points of coordinate $r > 2$ (there's something similar with the *Schwarzschild metric* written in *isotropic* coordinates).

Also, the ***proper radial distance*** of a point of coordinate $r < 2$ to the observer located at $r = 0$ is easily computed :
$$\tag{7}
\mathcal{D} = a(t) \ln{\Big(\displaystyle{\frac{2 + r}{2 - r}}\Big)} \equiv 2 \, a(t) \arg\tanh{(r/2)}.
$$
(this is simply $\mathcal{D} = a(t) \, \chi$ if you do the transformation (4) above).  That distance diverge at $r = 2$, so we can't define the distance to points of $r > 2$.

Am I right in saying that the part of spacetime with $r > 2$ can be interpreted as a *disconnected* "parallel" open universe, a bit like the second sheet of a **2 sheets hyperboloid** ? (see the picture there : http://virtualmathmuseum.org/Surface/hyperboloid2/hyperboloid2.html)

Comment: @JohnRennie, no it is not !  With $k = -1$ and the geometric factor $$\frac{1}{(1 + k r^2 /4)^2},$$ the metric (1) describes an *open* space (hyperbolic).  Check your maths/books and compare with metric (3), which have *an opposite sign in front of $k$*.  I'm sure of this.  The closed universe is defined for $k = +1$, so it would give the geometric factor $$\frac{1}{(1 + r^2/4)^2}.$$  The metric (3) then has the factor $$\frac{1}{1 - \tilde{r}^2}$$ for the *closed* universe.

Comment: Also, take note that the metrics (1) and (3) get an *hyperbolic* $\sinh{\chi}$, when you substitute the coordinate transformation (4) (or $\tilde{r} = \sinh{\chi}$).  This then ***implies*** the *open* universe, not the closed one (which need a *trigonometric* $\sin{\chi}$) !

Comment: Oops, sorry, I read the post in a hurry and misread it.

Comment: Isn't your metric (1) the Poincare disk, or one of its many varients?

Comment: @JohnRennie, metric (1) is a variant of the Poincaré "disk" (in 3D + time) if $k = -1$, but I think it isn't important (it's "just" a name !).  Most authors are defining the RW metric with metric (3) (metric (1) appears to be less well known), but a simple radial coordinate transformation gives metric (1).  Misner-Thorne-Wheeler give metric (1) on page 722 as the "true" RW metric (from the 1935-1936 papers of Robertson and Walker).  It has many calculations advantages since it is "isotropic", and its space section is conformal to the euclidian metric ; $d\ell^2 = f(r)(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)$.

Comment: I'm curious because after looking through many texts as well as internet sources, I cannot find any mention of this metric (1) with a $r^2/4$ term. What text were you using? Where did the 4 come from? Additionally, almost every source I could find had the $\frac{1}{(1+kr^2)^2}$ factor applied only to the $dr^2$ term, not to the $d\Omega^2$ term. I assume you put this in verbatim from the text you were reading, which is why I'd like to know specifically which one it is. So that I might read it for further context and insight

Comment: @Jim, that metric is given in Misner-Thorne-Wheeler and also in Landau-Lifchitz, as small addendum or exercice.  I have seen it elsewhere too, but I don't remember which book or paper.  All the other books I have are giving version (3) (with the $1/(1 - k \, \tilde{r}^2)$ factor in front of $d\tilde{r}^2$.  See the sign difference in front of $k$, by the way, it's important).  You can apply the radial coordinate transformation I have given to pass from one version to another, it's very easy.  The 4 is a bit arbitrary, but I keep it to satisfy conventions.  Again, try the transformation (2).

Comment: I'm going through the specific problem you refer to. I think some errors in calculation were made. The metric they give is absent a scale factor because it's included in $K=k/a^2(t)$. They also list the metric in cartesian coordinates. In this, $K$ is not limited to $K=-1,0,+1$. $K$ can have any magnitude. Also, if you do the replacement of cartesian to spherical, the text points out on the very next page that you should get your (3) (except there should be a $1-Kr^2$ in the denominator because $K$ still includes $a$.

Comment: I get that you can transform to spherical coordinates without imposing that $2\pi r$ be the proper circumference, but then you are still left with no scale factor in the numerator and $(1-\frac{r^2}{4a^2(t)})^2$ in the denominator. To which you might make the point that if $r>2a(t)$, the same question arises. The difference being that in this case, $a$ is in units of length, which mostly makes it impossible to have $r>2a$. I need to keep reading up on that, but I think it's the reason there isn't more of an issue surrounding this and I'd bet it's mentioned in the papers by Robertson and Walker

Comment: Even in the textbook, earlier in the page, it makes reference to $a(t)$ sometimes being called the "radius of the universe" in this formalism. As I said, I'm going to look at this some more, but I'd wager it's not a real problem because of the way each element is defined. Likely this question amounts to asking "What happens if one coordinate is larger than itself?"

Comment: @Jim, there's no mistake anywhere.  The scale factor is usually factorized out for convenience, and it's of no importance for the topic discussed here.  You could set it to 1 if you prefer.  In MTW's book, the $K$ can be absorbed by using $K = \pm \, |K|$, and then absorbing $|K|$ into the radial coordinate.  So you are left with $k = \pm 1, 0$ only (like what MTW are showing in their book).  In my opinion, metric (1) should be much more shown and well known.  Be sure to clearly see the difference in factors $1/(1 + k \, r^2 / 4)^2$ (global factor) and $1/(1 - k \, \tilde{r}^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a complete and clear understanding of the second universe in the RW metric (1) shown in the question.  It is indeed a second sheet of a 2 sheets hyperboloid.

For $k = -1$, the standard RW metric is derived by almost every author as a *pseudo-sphere* (actually a 2 sheets *hyperboloid*) of equation
$$\tag{1}
u^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = a^2,
$$
immersed in a *fictious flat space* of pseudo-euclidian metric
$$\tag{2}
d\ell^2 = -\: du^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2.
$$
Equation (1) is similar to the special relativistic mass shell relation $E^2 - p_x^2 - p_y^2 - p_z^2 = m^2$ (two sheets hyperboloid).

Most authors are using a partial parametrization, describing only *half* of the hypersurface (1) :
\begin{align}\tag{3}
u(\chi, \vartheta, \varphi) &= a \cosh{\chi}, \\[6pt]
x(\chi, \vartheta, \varphi) &= a \sinh{\chi} \, \sin{\vartheta} \, \cos{\varphi}, \\[6pt]
y(\chi, \vartheta, \varphi) &= a \sinh{\chi} \, \sin{\vartheta} \, \sin{\varphi}, \\[6pt]
z(\chi, \vartheta, \varphi) &= a \sinh{\chi} \, \cos{\vartheta}.
\end{align}
As you can see, this parametrization is assuming $u \ge a$, and yet equation (1) also admits the same parametrization with $u \le -\, a$ (changing the sign of $u$ in (3)).
When you substitute the parametrization (3) into the flat metric (2), you get the space section of the standard RW metric, with $k = -1$ and $0 < \chi < \infty$ :
$$\tag{4}
ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2(t) \big( d\chi^2 + \sinh^2 \chi \, (d\vartheta^2 + \sin^2 \vartheta \; d\varphi^2) \big).
$$
So this is only *half the hyperboloid*, which is just equivalent as making a topological choice (i.e. removing the second part of the fictious hypersurface).  But then, it is easy to prove that the full Robertson-Walker metric below, with $r < 2$ **and** $r > 2$, is actually decribing the full hyperboloid (1) (i.e. its two disconnected sheets) :
$$\tag{5}
ds^2 = dt^2 - \frac{a^2(t)}{(1 - \frac{1}{4} \; r^2)^2} \big( dr^2 + r^2 (d\vartheta^2 + \sin^2 \vartheta \; d\varphi^2) \big).
$$
The coordinate singularity at $r = 2$ is simply the gap between both sheets of the double-hyperboloid.  The link between coordinates $r$ and $u$ is this ($a$ is considered as a constant here, as in equation (1) and parametrization (3)) :
$$\tag{6}
r = 2 \, \sqrt{\displaystyle{\frac{u - a}{u + a}}}.
$$
It is actually very simple.  There is no weirdness, no mystery.  The metric (5) is all consistent with equation (1).  So as a *topological choice*, you may really have *two **disconnected** hyperbolic universes* (i.e. "parallel" universes), described by the natural *extension* of metric (5) to all values available of the radial coordinate.

---

**EDIT :** I'm adding some funny speculations.  In the analysis given above, both sheet-universes are expanding at exactly the same rate (same scale factor $a(t)$ for both hyperbolic sheets).

1. Could these sheets be a simple example of *branes* in the context of classical General Relativity ?
2. Could they be the "reverse" of each other, i.e. one of matter and the other one of anti-matter ?
3. Could we generalize them to two sheets of different scale factors, expanding at a different rate; $a_{+}(t)$ and $a_{-}(t)$, so they have different amount or type of matter ?  What would look like a "generalisation" of the RW metric (5) in this case ?

I guess the answer is "Yes" to 1 and 2.  In case of question 3, it may be trivial; just change the scale factor to a position dependant function: $a(t, \, r) = a_{+}(t) \; \text{if} \; r < 2$ and $a_{-}(t) \; \text{if} \; r > 2$.